# How to store the value of a checkbox if i uncheck it and switch back to same slide?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, angular

Behaviour : The checkbox is set as true by default in backend code , hence even if i uncheck the checkbox in JS, the checkbox value is set as true when i switch from other slide to current slide.

Expectation : Checkbox should be unchecked if i uncheck it and the updated value should be stored , so when i select the same slide again , the checkbox should be unchecked .

Javascript code for checkbox :

```
    function getSlideShowDetailPropList() {     
     var publish = {
                type: "checkbox",
                id: "Publish",
                displayName: "Active",
                propertyDefinition: {
                    value: angular.isDefined(activePortalComponent) ? activePortalComponent.viewModel.actSlideShow.publish : ""
                }
            };
     return [publish];

   if (id === "Publish") {
 activePortalComponent.viewModel.actSlideShow.publish = value;
     }              
   }
```

Csharp Code where the checkbox is hardcoded to true:

```
    public bool publish { get; set; }

    provider.cs

   private Slideshow CreateSlideshow(int i)
            {
                Slideshow slideshow1 = new Slideshow();
                slideshow1.publish = true;
                return slideshow1;
            }
```

getproperties.cs for returning the checkbox value:

```
    public IDictionary<string, object> GetSlideshowProperties( Slideshow foundSlideshow, IReadOnlyList<string> propertyNames )
            {
                var result = new Dictionary<string, object>();

                foreach (string propertyName in propertyNames)
                {
                     if (propertyName == "publish")
                    {
                        result.Add(propertyName, foundSlideshow.publish);
                    }
                }
            return result;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the boolean value you get from backend in a component variable say `stateChecked`, then bind this value to the checkbox state `checked` in your template as below.

in your component, toggle the checkbox on click, this way when your page loads the checkbox will be checked by default as the backend sends true, however on UI you can change the state of checkbox :

```
updateState() { 
    this.stateChecked = !this.stateChecked
}
```